# Is it possible to create an inner join between two tables showing all B that contain A?

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I have two tables: Kanji, and Vocabulary. Imagine the kanji table looks like this:

```
目
一
人
```

And the vocabulary table looks like this:

```
目的
一番目
一人
二人
人々
注目
目標
一匹
```

I want to generate a table that finds all vocabulary which contains the kanji in the kanji table and list them together. So the end result would look like this:

```
人   一人
    二人
    人々
一   一人
    一番目
    一匹
目   目的
    一番目
    注目
    目標
```

I'm not sure how to go about this. If I have just one kanji, I can use the QUERY function to generate all of the vocabularies which contain that one kanji. But can I create a dynamic table which essentially inner joins the "kanji" and "vocabulary" tables, looking for every instance of "vocabulary" contains "kanji"?

I tried using a QUERY to combine the two tables, but it won't work because the tables are mismatched in size:

```
=QUERY({C1:C296,D1:D224}, "SELECT Col2 WHERE Col1 contains Col2")
```

In the above example, the C column / Col2 is vocabulary, the D column / Col1 is kanji.

Is there a way to do this using Google Sheets?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest workaround is to get intersections by 1 value:

`=FILTER(D:D;REGEXMATCH(D:D;"目"))`

[image]

The picture shows how to use the copy of this function to get all intersections

---

The other approach is to use big array-formula like:

`=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(",";1;TRANSPOSE(ARRAYFORMULA(IF(REGEXMATCH(A1:A8;TRANSPOSE(B1:B3));A1:A8;))));","))`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SORT(TRIM(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(C1:C, REPT("(.)", LEN(C1:C)))), 
 TEXTJOIN("|", 1, A1:A)))<>"", "♦"&IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(IFERROR(
 REGEXEXTRACT(C1:C, REPT("(.)", LEN(C1:C)))), TEXTJOIN("|", 1, A1:A)))&"♣"&C1:C, ))
 ,,999^99)),,999^99), "♦")), "♣"))))
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 0):

seriously, much better way, just add a custom function:

```
/**
 * inner join on equality 
 *
 * @param {Range} items1 Table 1
 * @param {Range} items2 Table 2
 * @param {Integer} ix1 0-based index of key in Table1
 * @param {Integer} ix2 0-based index of key in Table2
 *
 * @customfunction

 * @author marc meyer (marqueymarc)
 */
function innerJoinEQ(items1 = [[]], items2 = [[]], ix1= 0, ix2= 0) {
  var res = [];
  var item2ix = 0;
  var map = new Map();

  items1 = Array.isArray(items1)? items1: [[items1]];
  items2 = Array.isArray(items2)? items2: [[items2]];
  
  items2.forEach((item2) => {
    let entries = map.get(item2[ix2]) || [];
    entries.push(item2);
    map.set(item2[ix2], entries);
  });
  items1.forEach((item1) => {
    let entries = map.get(item1[ix1]) || [];
    entries.forEach((rightPart) => {
      let cp = rightPart.slice();
      cp.splice(ix2, 1);
      res.push([...item1, ...cp]);
    })
  });
  return res;
}
```